# DateFormat giving wrong answer

Tags: java, date

I was using the below code to format a date. But it is giving unexpected result when I give data in incorrect format.

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

String dateVal = "3/8/2016 12:00:00 AM";

try {
    Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateVal);
    String formattedVal = outputFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println("formattedVal : "+formattedVal);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    throw pe;
}
```

In the above case, output is - formattedVal : 0009-02-05.

Instead of throwing the Parse exception, it is parsing the value and giving me an incorrect output. Can someone please help me to understand this anomalous behavior.

Comment: how should be expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` uses a `Calendar` object internally. The `Calendar` class has two modes, *lenient* and *strict*. In *lenient* mode, the default, it accepts out-of-range values for the different fields and normalizes these by adjusting other fields, in your case advancing the year field by about five hand a half.

Try setting the `SimpleDateFormat` calendar instance to strict:

```
inputFormat.setLenient(false);
```

You really should use `java.time` classes instead, or JodaTime if Java 8 is not an option.

Comment: Great explanation of lenient and strict behaviors, wise suggestions for `java.time` or `JodaTime`! +1

Answer (score 7):

The date parser does its best effort to parse the given string into date.

Here `3/8/2016` is parsed with format year/month/day so:

- year = 3
- month = 8 --> 8 months are 0.667 years
- day = 2016 --> 2016 days are ~5.5 years

so year = 3 + 5.5 = 8.5 + 0.667 = 9.17. This gives 05 Feb. 09.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year):

> Year: ...
>   Any other numeric string, such as a one digit string, a three or more
>   digit string, or a two digit string that isn't all digits (for
>   example, "-1"), is interpreted literally. So "01/02/3" or "01/02/003"
>   are parsed, using the same pattern, as Jan 2, 3 AD. Likewise,
>   "01/02/-3" is parsed as Jan 2, 4 BC.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String dateVal = "3/8/2016 12:00:00 AM";
            DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");//the pattern here need to bee equals the 'dateVal' format

            DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateVal);
            String formattedVal = outputFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println("formattedVal : "+formattedVal);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            System.err.println("cannot parse date...");
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code looks correct, it does not answer the OP's question: Explain behavior.